# How can I override the empty search message?

Tags: 8, search

What do I have to do to override the message

> Your search yielded no results

from core search module inside `core/modules/search/src/Controller/SearchController.php`?

Answer (score 5):

You can implement [`template_preprocess_item_list`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_item_list/8.2.x) (or [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) to be precise) in your theme or module to override that.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_item_list().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_item_list__search_results(&$variables) {

  $variables['empty']['#markup'] = '<h3>' . t('Foobar') . '</h3>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace empty search message by call custom block body by:

- Go to /code/themes/THEMENAME
- open THEMENAME.theme file and add following Hook

As:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_item_list__search_results(&$variables) {
  $custom_block = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block_content')->load('BLOCKNUMBER');
  $fieldcontent = $custom_block->body->value;
  $variables['empty']['#markup'] = $fieldcontent;
}
```

Please change THEMENAME with you theme name and BLOCKNUMBER with your block number.